# why a loop condition can run indefinitely when compares int to short

Tags: java, int, primitive-types, short

There is a loop used in my code, for which coverity is throwing the error -

> Infinite loop, loop_bound_type_mismatch: Loop bound someArray.length
> has type int, which is wider in size or has a bigger upper bound than
> the type short of loop counter shortTypeVariable, the loop condition
> may always be true.

This is a sample code for which this error is thrown :

```
short shortTypeVariable = 0;

while(shortTypeVariable < someArray.length) 
{//some work}
```

I am not able to figure in which condition it can run indefinitely. I know its not  right condition to match but when it can be wrong and can run indefinitely.

Comment: The `some work` part is actually important to know if this runs forever. Also `when it can be wrong` is not phrased well as the condition has to be true for the loop to run indefinitely. Finally, what do you mean `I am not able to figure in which condition it can run indefinitely`? You actually wrote that exact condition in the `()` after the `while`

Comment: Are you sure this is an error? This looks more like a warning to me. It's warning you that because your variable is of type `short`, it might not be able to reach a value so high that it could be greater than `length`, which, as an  `int`, can store higher numbers.

Comment: @Mark, editted the code to show that in somework the short variable gets increment by 1. "I am not able to figure in which condition it can run indefinitely" : by this I am trying to understand why coverity is throwing this error and where it can go wrong.

Comment: @Schred you caught the problem. I got it now. Its an error only but I understood what it meant now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show what the explanation means...

Change the loop to have: (33000 assumes a large array length, wider than short)

```
while (shortTypeVariable < 33000)
{
    shortTypeVariable++;
    System.out.println("" + shortTypeVariable);
}
```

... then run it to see what happens. The data range of short is -32,768 to 32,767. After 32,767 is reached, the short overflows to -32,768 and keeps going... up to 0, and continues up to 32767 where the overflow happens *again* in a continuous cycle.

That is the possible infinite loop potential, as 33000 can never be reached because the int range (2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) is wider than the short range.

Comment: Still a strange thing to make an error out of. A warning? Maybe. Would still annoy me, but I could get behind that. An error is taking it too far. What if I need to use a short there? Do I actually need to create a helper int variable that will also never be that big as it will only contain whatever was in that short variable?

Comment: Looking at Coverity's info, that appears to be under their "common weakness" items, I can't find that it's necessarily an error. I don't know that I understand the concern or need for a short type when the compared value is an int. I mean, one _could_ (though it would not be me) first check if the `arr.length` is greater than `Short.MAX_VALUE`, and if so, take a different path to handle the situation. But to the original question of _why_ has been answered because of differing data type ranges.